# Expected binary or unicode string got 24 : Tensorflow Dataset numerical/categorical columns

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to declare numeric and categorical columns that I would feed to my tensorflow estimator.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

perform_shuffle = True
BATCH_SIZE = 1
repeat_count = 1

d = {
    'c1': ["Sony", "Samsung", "Sony", "Sony", "Samsung"], 
    'n2': [24,20,18,26,24],
    'n3': [1,0,0,1,1]
    }
features = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
labels = [0,1,0,0,1]



numeric_feature_column1 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="n2", dtype=tf.float32)
numeric_feature_column2 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="n3", dtype=tf.float32)
categorical_column1 = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(key="c1", hash_bucket_size=5)
feature_columns = [categorical_column1, numeric_feature_column1, numeric_feature_column2]

def my_input_fn(features, labels, perform_shuffle=False, repeat_count=1):

    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))

    if perform_shuffle:
        # Randomizes input using a window of 512 elements (read into memory)
        train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat(repeat_count) # Repeats dataset this # times
    train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)  # Batch size to use

    # create a iterator of the correct shape and type
    iterator = train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    batch_features, batch_labels = iterator.get_next()
    return batch_features, batch_labels

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
   feature_columns=feature_columns, 
   hidden_units=[40, 60, 30, 12], 
   n_classes=2,
   model_dir="./") # Path to where checkpoints etc are stored

classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: my_input_fn(features, labels, True, 1))
```

But even when I try this simple dataset I get the following error :

> TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got 24

I tried changing the order of the columns in my feature_columns array but it doesn't change anything. Column 2 is declared as numerical therefore it should expect at least an int or a float.
What am I missing here?

Comment: I tried to run your code and I got `TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> to Tensor.` in the line `train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))` - which makes sense because `features` is a `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: oh ok I thought I could input a pandas dataframe. It should only be a dict, right ? weird I didn't get the same error as you

Comment: [`tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices) expects a "nested structure of tensors, each having the same size in the 0th dimension". These can be created automatically from NumPy arrays I think, but not from `pd.DataFrame` or `dict`. I'm using TF 1.4.0, maybe you have a different version...

Comment: 1.5 I am saying dict because in the tutorial for loading CSV files the decode_csv function returns `d = dict(zip(feature_names, features)), label` . EDIT, I have tried with a dict and it works :)

Comment: What tutorial is that? [`tf.decode_csv`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_csv) is supposed to return a list of tensor objects... (btw, minor correction, TF can automatically create a tensor from a data frame as long as it has only one data type, in your case you have numbers and strings, so it fails - that's probably why they changed the message)

Comment: oh ok that explains why I managed to insert a dataframe some time ago with only floats inside. The tuto is https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-tensorflow-datasets.html but it is not tf.decode_csv but the nested decode_csv in the input function that returns the dict :) Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What does "nested structure of tensors" mean? I really wish they spare a few more words on such an important function